# Error in getting a contact from database

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, relational-database

```
public Cursor getContact(String e_mail) throws SQLException
        {
            String str[] = {KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PASSWORD};



            Cursor mCursor = db.query("Users_Detail", str, KEY_EMAIL + "=" + e_mail, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
                    if (mCursor != null) {
                        mCursor.moveToFirst();
                    }
                    return mCursor;
        }
```

As you can see in my code I'm trying to access contact from my database. But there is some problem in the functioning.
The statement

**"KEY_EMAIL + "=" + e_mail"**

is the main problem i guess... **

Plz.. help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try on this way:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "Users_Details",
            str,
            "KEY_EMAIL" + "='" + email + "'", null, null, null, null,
            null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
```

Comment: @user3269876 what is the ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code`

```
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Users_Detail WHERE KEY_EMAIL = '"
            + e_mail + "'";
    int data = 0;
    db1 = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        //getDetails
    }
    cursor.close();
    db1.close();
```

Comment: can u post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

here help is object of helper class

help.KEY_EMAIL+"="+ "'"+cnt+"'"

Comment: add "e_mail" instead of "cnt"

Answer (score 0):

use this code and I checked it.

```
Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                        Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                        Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
                int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID);
                int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.PHOTO_ID);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    cursor.getString(contactIdIdx);
                    String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
                    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
```